# sql replace null value with value with value in other column

Tags: sql

I want to replace all values which has a NULL value with the the value in another column on the same row.

I have tried different sql statements without any success.

Regards

Comment: Post (add to your question) your best effort so far.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *update your table* in the way you describe, or that you want to perform such a replacement *in the results of a query*?

Comment: What is one of the different SQL statements that you have already tried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to update, do something like this:

```
update t set col1 = col2
where col1 is null
```

If you just want to do selection, use most databases support `coalesce`:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2) from t;
```

Comment: what if `col2` is null itself

Comment: At least in Postgresql:
If all arguments are null, the COALESCE function will return null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Update the value from same column

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Col1 = A.Col2
From TableA A
Where A.Col1 IS NULL
```

If you want to update the value from Other table then Try this:

```
Update A
SET A.Column1 = B.Column1
From TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.SomeID = B.SameID
WHERE A.Column1 IS NULL
```

You can update the value by using join and update query.